# why my django id field get the value of user field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, faker

Im new in django.
I want to make a script that can make fake data with faker [enter link description here](https://faker.readthedocs.io/)
this is my model.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

#additional
blood_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,blank=True)
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
case =models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

this is my fake data function
fake_first_name is variabale that has fake name that faker generated and so on for other variables

```
    def populate(N=5):
    for entery in range(N):
        #making fake data
        fake_first_name = fakergen.first_name()
        fake_last_name = fakergen.last_name()
        fake_email = fakergen.email()
        fake_password = fakergen.password(length=10)
        fake_blood_type = random.choice(bloodType)
        fake_phone = fakergen.phone_number()
        fake_case = random.choice(Case)
    Create new User entery
    user = User.objects.get_or_create(
        username=fake_first_name, 
        first_name=fake_first_name, 
        last_name=fake_last_name, 
        email=fake_email)[0]
    tempUser = User.objects.get(username=fake_first_name)
    tempUser.set_password(fake_password)
    tempUser.save()
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
        user=fake_first_name,
        blood_type=fake_blood_type, 
        phone_number=fake_phone,  
        case=fake_case,
        description='')[0]
```

I don't know if this is the right way for creating object when we have to table with one to one relationship.
in here : 
`userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
        user=fake_first_name,` i think if `user` would be equal to the key for User model the connection between my table model would be ok.

and i get this error:
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Lisa'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `user` as value for the `user` of your `UserProfile`, not `fake_first_name`:

```
user = User.objects.get_or_create(
    username=fake_first_name, 
    first_name=fake_first_name, 
    last_name=fake_last_name, 
    email=fake_email)[0]
user.set_password(fake_password)
user.save()
userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
    user=user,
    blood_type=fake_blood_type, 
    phone_number=fake_phone,  
    case=fake_case,
    description='')[0]
```

Comment: in that case I get this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username` i don' t know if this is related to the previous problem or not

Comment: @gazegan: that is because you make two `User`s with the *same* `username` in your database, but the `username` should be *unique*.